# Dividing in a do while loop-Java

Tags: java, debugging

i was given the following assignment for school....so far ive gotten all but one part finish, i Just started learning Java 2 1/2 weeks ago so i dont know a whole lot. You must use TextIO methods to read the file. As you read the file, count the total number of ice cream cones that were sold. (This is the same as the 
number of lines that you read from the file.) Also count the total number of "Strawberry" cones that were sold.
At the end of the program, print out the total number of cones, the number of Strawberry cones, and the percentage of cones that were Strawberry.
Note: To do this program, you have to know when to stop reading from the file. TextIO has a function named TextIO.eof() to check whether the entire file has been read. The value of this function is true if the entire file has been read. The value is false if there is more data in the file. You want to continue reading from the file as long as TextIO.eof() is false."

if i could get some help finding the bug that isnt allowing me to divide the number of strawberry flavors by the total number of flavors in the file to get the percentage that would be great....please only tell me where i went wrong i want to learn this without people telling me how to write the code, i just need help debugging right now.

here is what ive finished so far with the code

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author chris
 */
public class countCones {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            txtIO.readFile("C:/Users/chris/Documents/Java/Java/New folder/icecream.dat");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            txtIO.putln("Error: File didn't open");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String countFlava = txtIO.getln();
        String strawberryFlavor;
        int total = 0;
        double strawberryPercentage;
        int strawb = 1;

        int totalFlavor;

        do {
            countFlava = txtIO.getln();
            total = total + 1;

            if (countFlava.equals("strawberry")) {
                int cStrawb = strawb++;
            }


            strawberryPercentage = total / strawb;
        } while (!txtIO.eof());
        {
            txtIO.putln(strawberryPercentage);
        }
        txtIO.putln(total);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are dividing the total by the number of strawberries. Shouldn't it be the opposite?

Comment: Change one of the operands of the division to a floating point number to avoid integer division. You should also divide after the loop, not inside it.

Comment: And start counting the number of strawberry cones from zero, not from 1.

Comment: and i would also put the calculation after the while - no need to do the calculation every iteration.

Comment: and ... maybe remove the block(the curlies) around txtIO.putln(strawberryPercentage); they are prone to be irritating after the while.